# Showing only previous output

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, runtime-error, runtime

I recently starting javascript.iam facing a problem whenever I run my javascript code in vs code it's showing only previous output.

No matter how many times I change my code it still showing previous code

I try even delete my vs code completely re install it again re install node js but my problem doesn't solve

Comment: We can't help diagnose the problem without seeing the code. Please include all relevant code, as text, preferably as a stack snippet.

Comment: Console.log(lemon) first code it's correct but when changed second time from lemon to mango it's remain lemon

Comment: How you are changing the variable and how it's initialized matter; please include all relevant code in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.